# Kohana 3 ORM: Getting most repeated values, ranked, and inserting into new object / array

Tags: orm, kohana-3, kohana-orm

So, another in my series of Kohana 3 ORM questions :)

I have, essentially, a pivot table, called `connections`. The `connections` table connects a `song` to a `keyword`. That's all great and working (thanks to my last two questions!)

I want to output the most connected songs by keyword. So, to somehow query my `connections` table and output an object (with an arbitrarily limited number of iterations `$n`) that ranks songs by the number of times they have been connected, ie. the number of times that particular `song_id` appears for that particular `keyword_id`.

I have literally no idea how to achieve this, without querying every single row (!!!) and then counting those individual results in an array.... There must be a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is more of an SQL question. Using the DB query builder:

```
DB::select('songs.*')->select(array('COUNT("keywords.id")', 'nconnections'))
  ->from('songs')
  ->join('connections', 'LEFT')->on('connections.song_id', '=', 'songs.id')
  ->join('keywords', 'LEFT')->on('connections.keyword_id', '=', 'keywords.id')
  ->group_by('songs.id')
  ->order_by('nconnections')
  ->as_object('Model_Song')
  ->execute();
```

or in SQL

```
SELECT `songs`.*, COUNT(`keywords`.`id`) AS `nconnections` FROM songs
  LEFT JOIN `connections` ON `connections`.`song_id` = `songs`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `keywords` ON `connections`.`keyword_id` = `keywords`.`id`
GROUP BY `songs`.`id` ORDER BY `nconnections`
```

should return the result you want.

You'll want to have an accessible property called `nconnections` in your song model. The simplest way to do that is to add a public member so you don't tamper with ORM's inner workings.

---

I'm assuming you're using a model called 'Song', linked to a 'songs' table, a 'Keyword' model linked to a 'keywords' table and in the 'connections' table foreign keys 'song_id' and 'keyword_id' for each model respectively.